# combobox inside a datagridview with bound data

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I've created a Datagridview that is bound to a Class CTag.
Inside CTAG I have 2 members that I want to show in the datagridview : name, area
The columns are created automatically because the class CTag is connected as datasource to the Datagridview. But I want to limit wat the user enters inside the "area" column. So in that place I want to have a combobox.
I already found out how to add a new combobox with a list of options in the datagridview, but it creates an extra column this way.

```
private BindingList<string> listOfAreas         = new BindingList<string>();

listOfAreas.Add("PE");
listOfAreas.Add("PA");
listOfAreas.Add("MK");
listOfAreas.Add("DB");
listOfAreas.Add("CT");
listOfAreas.Add("TM");

dgvTags.DataSource = listOfTags;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn area = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
area.Name = "DataArea";
area.DataPropertyName = "DataArea";
area.DataSource = listOfAreas;
dgvTags.Columns.Add(area);
```

What am I missing to get this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line:

```
dgvTags.DataSource = listOfTags;
```

After this:

```
dgvTags.Columns.Add(area);
```

Explanation:

When the AutoGenerateColumns property is true (default), when you set the DataSource, columns are created for each property of the type of the list **if there is no column for that property**.

Therefore, if you add the column before placing it in DataSource, you will avoid a double column.